# in kitkat 4.4 API level 19 hindi language characters not showing

Tags: android

in kitkat 4.4 API level 19 hindi language characters not showing. what is the reason in higher version 5.0 and above it working properly

sample code i've tried (in following code my txt_sample sowing only english character)

```
TextView txt_sample;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         txt_sample=findViewById(R.id.txt_sample);
        txt_sample.setText("AC और DC Current में क्या अंतर है");
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input. Also, try using `AppCompatTextVIew` or `MaterialTextView` to see if the situation improves.

Comment: i taken some sample code

Comment: Have you tried using other textviews I mentioned above in place of `txt_sample`

Comment: @AjayPawar I'm stuck with the same problem. Did you find any solution?